# Lookup Values and sum values in cell pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vlookup

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Code' : ['10', '100', '1010'],
                     'Value' : [25, 50, 75]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                     'Codes' : ['10', '100;1010', '100'],
                     'Value' : [25, 125, 50]})
```

Column "Codes" in df2 can contain multiple codes separated by ";". If this is the case, I need to sum up their values from df1.

I tried .map(), but this did not work for rows with multiple codes in a row. Also, I end up converting code '1010' to value '2525'.

How do I specify a perfect match and the summation for ";" separated values?

Comment: Though coming to see this question a bit late, you can also take a look at my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `explode()` the list of **Codes**
- `merge()` with **df1** and calculate total, grouping on the index of **df2**
- have created a new column with this calculated

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Code": ["10", "100", "1010"], "Value": [25, 50, 75]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"ID": ["A", "B", "C"], "Codes": ["10", "100;1010", "100"], "Value": [25, 125, 50]}
)

df2.join(
    df2["Codes"]
    .str.split(";")
    .explode()
    .reset_index()
    .merge(df1, left_on="Codes", right_on="Code")
    .groupby("index")
    .agg({"Value": "sum"}),
    rsuffix="_calc",
)
```

|  | ID | Codes | Value | Value_calc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 10 | 25 | 25 |
| 1 | B | 100;1010 | 125 | 125 |
| 2 | C | 100 | 50 | 50 |

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum(df1, df2):
    df1['sum'] = df1['Value'] + df2['Value']
    print(df1)


df1.loc[df2['Codes'].isin(df1['Code'])].apply(sum(df1, df2))
```

---

If the code in df2 is in df1 theen add values

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can make a lookup table of `Code` to `Value` mapping from `df1`, then use `.map()` on `df2` to map the expanded list of `Codes` to the mapping.  Finally, sum up the mapped values for the same `ID` to arrive at the desired value, as follows:

**1. Make a lookup table of `Code` to `Value` mapping from `df1`:**

```
mapping = df1.set_index('Code')['Value']
```

**2. Use `.map()` on `df2` to map the expanded list of `Codes` to the mapping.  Sum up the mapped values for the same `ID` to arrive at the desired value:**

```
df2a = df2.set_index('ID')             # set `ID` as index

df2a['value_map'] = (
    df2a['Codes'].str.split(';')       # split by semicolon 
                 .explode()            # expand splitted values into rows
                 .map(mapping)         # map Code from mapping                
                 .groupby('ID').sum()  # group sum by ID
    )

df2 = df2a.reset_index()               # reset `ID` from index back to data column
```

**Result:**

```
print(df2)

  ID     Codes  Value  value_map
0  A        10     25         25
1  B  100;1010    125        125
2  C       100     50         50
```